# ssh permission denied from remote host

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

When I ssh from my box (Arch Linux) to a remote box (Fedora server) using a key, it works with one user (user1) but don't with user2. Both users use the same ssh key: the one in user2 ssh home folder. (`/home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa` with correct modes).

On remote host, both users have a home directory with the same `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

**EDIT**

As per request, some config file:

**On remote host**:

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Port XXXX
Allowusers user1 user2
PermitRootLogin without-password
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
#HostbasedAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes

$ journalctl -u sshd
Accepted publickey for user1 from XX.YY.XX.YY port XXXX ssh2: RSA SHA256:WT722lmf2CkXC8T6hGScDl+wZW71Ls3/U2W8FHh+vK4  <-- when connecting as user1
Connection closed by authenticating user user2 XX:YY:XX:YY port XXX [preauth]  <-- when connecting as user2
```

user2 (non working) home dir:

```
ls -la /home/user2
drwx------. 2 user2 user  4.0K Jan 31 19:18 .ssh/
 ls -la /home/user2/.ssh
-rw-------. 1 user2 user2   393 Jan 31 18:12 authorized_keys
```

Selinux enabled on the server (default for fedora). Please note that user1 is the default existing user when server is new and user2 has been added by myself.

user1 (working)

```
ls -Za /home/user1
 unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 .ssh/ 
ls -Za /home/user1/.ssh
 unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 ./  unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 ../       unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 authorized_keys
```

user2 (non working)

```
ls -Za /home/user2 
unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 .ssh/
ls -Za /home/user2/.ssh
unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 ./  unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 ../      unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 authorized_keys
```

diff: *r:unlabeled* vs *r:ssh_home_*

**On local box**:

```
user2@hortensia ➤➤ ~ % ls -al .ssh
-rw-------   1 user2 user2  1.8K Jan 16 18:19 id_rsa
-rw-------   1 user2 user2   396 Jan 16 18:19 id_rsa.pub
user2@hortensia ➤➤ ~ % ls -al
drwx------    2 user2 user2  4.0K Feb  1 08:06  .ssh/
```

I can't figure out why ssh is working for user1 and not for user2.
On remote host, I stoped *sshguard* and *iptables*, but it don't change anything. The *sshd_config* is very basic, has a line **Allowusers** with user1 and user2 and allow connection with key.
When running ssh in verbose mode, I can see difference in message when user1 or user2 connect.

**user1**

```
 $ ssh -vv -p XX user1@XX.YY.XX.YY
 ....................
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:WT722lmf2CkXC8T6hGScDl+wZW71Ls3/U2W8FHh+vK4 /home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa
 debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
 debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
 debug2:input_userauth_pk_ok:SHA256:WT722lmf2CkXC8T6hGScDl+wZW71Ls3/U2W8FHh+vK4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
 Authenticated to XX.YY.XX.YY ([XX.YY.XX.YY]:XXXX).
 debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
 debug2: channel 0: send open
 debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
 debug1: Entering interactive session.
 debug1: pledge: network
 debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
 debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
 debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
 debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
 debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
 debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
 debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
 debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
 debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
 debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
 debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
 debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
 debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
 Last login: Thu Feb  1 07:08:04 2018 from XX.YY.XX.YY
 [user1@dahlia ~]$
```

Now, when connecting with **user2**

```
$ ssh -vv -p XX user2@XX.YY.XX.YY
...........
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:WT722lmf2CkXC8T6hGScDl+wZW71Ls3/U2W8FHh+vK4 /home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user2@XX.YY.XX.YY: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

After more than one day I am still unable to fix this error. Thank you for help/hints.

Comment: Don't tell what you have in your configuration files. Post the actual content of your configuration files, along with the permissions of the .ssh directories and files. The problem might be something you deem irrelevant.

Comment: Also, `/var/log/auth.log` on the server may tell you more.

Comment: post has been updated with more info

Comment: please also add `ls -la` for the non working user on the server.

Comment: post updated again as requested

Comment: Just as I thought, your server has selinux enabled. Please also run `ls -Za .ssh` on both users on your server (working and non working). Most probably the wrong selinux context is set.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider It is the only settings I didn't investigated as I am very new to Selinux. And in fact, the output show one diff as noted in OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ls -l` output shows that additionally to the normal permissions selinux contexts are set:

```
ls -la /home/user2/.ssh
-rw-------. 1 user2 user2   393 Jan 31 18:12 authorized_keys
          ^ this dot indicates additional selinux contextes
```

Your `ls -Z` output shows that the type context of your `.ssh` directory and the files in it is set to `unlabeled_t`:

```
ls -Za /home/user2/.ssh
unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 ./
```

This context has to be set to `ssh_home_t` so sshd can use it.

Run

```
chcon -R -t ssh_home_t .ssh
```

to set the context recursively on the `.ssh` directory.

Comment: # chcon -R -t ssh_home_t .ssh
# ls -Za /home/user2/.ssh  --> unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 authorized_keys.  Now I can ssh with user2 :-). Thank you so much for pointing this to me.